# Unit test fails when mocked object is inside lambda, but works when it's outside lambda and used inside lambda?

Tags: android, mockito, mockito-kotlin

I have a dialog that I'm doing some unit tests on using Mockito / Mockito Kotlin.

When the user clicks on the dialog, the user is shown a list of times, and then their selection assigns the value and then does some other work with it.

I have a timeProvider class that I've mocked which just returns the currentTime.

This is the part of the dialog where the selection happens

```
val currentTime = timeProvider.now()
dialogBuilder.setItems(context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.silenceTimes)) { _, which ->
            val silenceUntil: Long = when (which) {
                0 -> currentTime.plusMinutes(30).millis
                1 -> currentTime.plusHours(1).millis
                2 -> currentTime.plusHours(8).millis
                3 -> currentTime.plusHours(24).millis
                else -> 0
            }
        }
```

When the code is above, my unit test works as expected.  The logic inside the click event triggers, and the time is set to the currentTime plus 30 minutes.

```
        val items = arrayOf("0", "1", "2", "3")
        val captor = argumentCaptor<DialogInterface.OnClickListener>()
        val captor2 = argumentCaptor<DialogInterface>()

        whenever(timeProvider.now()).thenReturn(currentTime)
        whenever(dialogBuilder.setItems(eq(items), captor.capture())).thenReturn(dialogBuilder)

        verify(dialogBuilder).setItems(eq(items), captor.capture())
        captor.firstValue.onClick(captor2.capture(), eq(1))
```

But when I have the timeProvider inside the click lambda, it no longer functions and gives me an argument matcher error?

```
dialogBuilder.setItems(context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.silenceTimes)) { _, which ->

            val currentTime = timeProvider.now()

            val silenceUntil: Long = when (which) {
                0 -> currentTime.plusMinutes(30).millis
                1 -> currentTime.plusHours(1).millis
                2 -> currentTime.plusHours(8).millis
                3 -> currentTime.plusHours(24).millis
                else -> 0
            }
        }
```

> ```
> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
> Invalid use of argument matchers!
> 0 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
> -> at com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.KArgumentCaptor.capture(ArgumentCaptor.kt:105)
> -> at com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.MatchersKt.eq(Matchers.kt:34)
>
> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>     //incorrect:
>     someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
> When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
> For example:
>     //correct:
>     someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
>
> For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
>
>
>   at com.common.TimeProvider.now(TimeProvider.kt:8)
> ```

I can't figure out why the code works with the time outside the lambda, but not inside the lambda?

Ideally I wouldn't set it before the dialog because who knows how long they'd actually keep it open before clicking, but also, I might run into problems like this in the future which don't allow a workaround like that?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm still not sure what's going on here, but I realized that i was always getting back position 0 for the which value (I thought they 1 indexed it) so I tried removing the captor2.capture on this

captor.firstValue.onClick(captor2.capture(), eq(1))

Once I did that, and just passed in null,1 or null,2 it worked with the value in the lambda

¯_(ツ)_/¯

For now, I didn't need the other captor so I'm okay for now...